# How to model repeated occurrence of two types of events?

Tags: repeated-measures, modeling, stochastic-processes, propensity-scores, recurrent-events

I have data on N individuals, where for each individual there is data on the times at which he/she visits a treatment facility for getting treated for an acute health-related condition. There are 2 types of facilities, say A and B.  Both the times of visit, and the type of facility visited are stochastic.  Note that an individual can visit both A and B (multiple times) during the observation period.  I also have data on the fixed attributes of each individual (e.g., age, gender).  I would like to model the stochastic occurrence of visits and estimate the odds of visiting facility A at any given time t (relative to visiting B). My eventual goal is to compare the "quality" of treatment at facility A to that at facility B.  Hence, I am thinking that some type of "time-varying propensity score model" would be useful, if that makes sense.  Any suggestions on how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience, I would view histogram frequency of A/B visits to determine appropriate time-series granularity. A rough idea of relative frequency could also be determined.

Then depending on histogram frequency of visits if it's per hour, min, etc. and how accurate I wanted to be and the data available, I would train, validate, cross-validate and test a classification or regression model using a gradient boosted tree ensemble or LSTM targeting total facility A/B visits in time-series format and include other features like day of week, month, holiday, running day/hourly count, etc.

If model shows sufficient predictive power, I'd then use the model to make further predictions to help determine relative odds of visiting A wrt B at time t. Then I'd test again with fresh, new OOS data coming in to verify model's accuracy.

I'm sure there are other, better ways than above, but that's how a beginning modeler like me would do it.